# Resize qcow2 image on Ubuntu via WSL2? Kernel cannot be read by libguestfs-tools virt-resize

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wsl-2

I'm trying to resize a qcow2 img I created and installed a guest mac os. When I try to use virt-resize I get the following error:

`virt-resize: error: libguestfs error: /usr/bin/supermin exited with error status 1.`

This seems to have to do with not being able to access the kernel or wrong permissions on the kernel. I'm running Ubuntu via WSL2 and I'm not sure how to give libguestfs-tools access to the kernel WSL2 runs on. How would you do this?

Answer (score 7):

This comes about because there's not really a good way (at least, not any obvious one after a bit of time with Google) to get access to the WSL2 kernel from within WSL2 without custom-compiling your own.

In lieu of that, `libguestfs-tools` will work just fine if you install the normal Ubuntu kernel packages and do the usual Ubuntu follow-up step for `libguestfs-tools`:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
sudo chmod go+r /boot/vmlinuz-*
```

This will populate your `/boot` and `/lib/modules/*` directories with a kernel that will satisfy `libguestfs-tools`.